# Migrate passwords from Chrome to Firefox Quantum

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, passwords, password-management

Is there a way to import passwords from Chrome to Firefox Quantum?

I'm storing passwords in Chrome's manager, not using any 3rd party app (and don't want to).

There's no `passwords` option in Import Wizard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the import tool should do the trick of migrating passwords from chrome to firefox. You can find this tool within the Library. I'm not sure if you are referring to this import tool as the "Import Wizard".

--> Step-by-Step accessing the library:

- Press `Ctrl + Shift + B` in Firefox for Windows

or

- Press `Ctrl + Shift + O` in Firefox for Linux

or

- If your menu-bar is hidden, press `Alt` to make it appear.
- Click on `Bookmarks`
- Click on `Manage Bookmarks`

--> Once the Library window has opened:

- Click on the `Import and Backup` button
- Proceed as shown on the websites linked below

Sources: 
Firefox Support: "Import Bookmarks and personal data from another browser"
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/import-bookmarks-data-another-browser

howtogeek: "How to Migrate All Your Data From Chrome to Firefox"
https://www.howtogeek.com/333047/how-to-migrate-all-your-data-from-chrome-to-firefox/

ghacks: "How to import Bookmarks, Passwords and other data to Firefox"
https://www.ghacks.net/2017/09/25/how-to-import-bookmarks-passwords-and-other-data-to-firefox/

Comment: Yes, I followed those guides. The window opened after clicking Import Data from Another Browser is called Import Wizard but there's no `passwords/logins` option

Comment: Hmm.. then Firefox does'nt seem to find it. I can't help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this on my Linux rig (Linux showed 3 options as your graphic above shows -- no password import option). I logged in from Windows computer and saw all 4 options. Then opened the Linux computer and activated Firefox Sync. My passwords were now available!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see this as very helpful, since you mention Linux and Windows, when the OP is on a Mac. How did that solve the browser issue on your Linux side? Can you provide any screenshots or to help with your walk through if it did work for your Linux side?

Answer (score -2):

This is late reply for this question, however you can do this only on Microsoft windows even on a virtual machine you have.
Install both chrome and firefox and login to your account on both of them.

Open firefox menu, select Login and passwords and select import option, then select import from browser and choose chrome.
After finishing the import, select your account and choose sync now, to make sure your passwords are synced with your firefox account.